# unregistering broadcast receivers on screen off for better battery life

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, battery

i am making an android widget which is active only when the screen is on, to prolong battery life. so i have one service which run all the time and reacts to ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF. when the screen turns off i unregister other broadcast receivers and when the screen turns on i register them again.

my question is, what is the best practice, regarding battery life, to do when the screen turns off. is it better also to delete the broadcast receiver variables (i.e. m_Receiver = null;) or is unregistering enough? deleting means more free memory for the system, but causes garbage collection and extra memory operations (when the screen turns on i have to create a new receiver) which are expensive...

Answer (score 0):

> i am making an android widget which is active only when the screen is on, to prolong battery life.

First, I am going to assume that by "widget" you mean "app widget".

Second, an app widget is never "active".

> so i have one service which run all the time and reacts to ACTION_SCREEN_ON and ACTION_SCREEN_OFF.

This is not a good idea. First, you waste megabytes of RAM by keeping your process around. Second, it will not work, as Android will not let the service "run all the time" -- it will shut down your service for old age eventually. Third, users get irritated with developers like you who have services running all of the time, so they will kill off your service using a task killer (Android 2.1 and down) or by the Manage Services screen in the Settings application (Android 2.0 and higher).

> when the screen turns off i unregister other broadcast receivers and when the screen turns on i register them again.

I have no idea what "other broadcast receivers" are. They probably should not be registered in the first place.

> my question is, what is the best practice, regarding battery life, to do when the screen turns off. is it better also to delete the broadcast receiver variables (i.e. m_Receiver = null;) or is unregistering enough? deleting means more free memory for the system, but causes garbage collection and extra memory operations (when the screen turns on i have to create a new receiver) which are expensive...

Considering how much memory you are tying up with the service, worrying about this is pointless. Focus on getting rid of the everlasting service.

For example, suppose this app widget is showing battery level. Do not have an everlasting service that is watching `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED`. Instead, let the user choose a polling period (e.g., once every five minutes) and use `AlarmManager` to check the battery level on a periodic basis.

Comment: it is a widget only, no application. i am learning programming for android and as a first small project i am developing a battery widget so i register/unregister the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED accroding to screen state.

Comment: @shelll: "it is a widget only, no application" -- that is incorrect. First, please get the terminology right. The interactive elements of the home screen are each called an "app widget". A "widget" is a `Button`, `CheckBox`, etc. Second, anything you install on Android is an application. "so i register/unregister the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED accroding to screen state" -- please do not have a service running all of the time. Please use `AlarmManager` to check the battery state periodically.

Comment: @shelll: To check the battery state without a `BroadcastReceiver`, call `registerReceiver()` with a `null` first parameter and an `IntentFilter` for `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` for the second parameter. Since `ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED` is a sticky broadcast, the return value from `registerReceiver()` will be the last-broadcast battery state. Read the values out of the `Intent` extras and update the app widget's `RemoteViews`. Do this from a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` that is triggered by `AlarmManager`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: i have problems with previous reply, do not know how to make new paragraph and my edit took longer then the allowed limit. more info: i think that the alarm will be triggered many more times, then ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED, is it still a better way? the "alarm way" will not show precise battery state (e.g. charging status) all the time and users can complain. i will replace the receiver with alarm if you say it is better regarding battery life and user happiness. one more question. i set updatePeriodMillis to zero and in constructor start an alarm, which will not wake up the phone?

Comment: @shelll: "i think that the alarm will be triggered many more times, then ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" -- or many less times, depending on user configuration. "the 'alarm way' will not show precise battery state (e.g. charging status) all the time and users can complain" -- conceivably, but that's because they do not need your app widget, as there are already *many* other ways for them to determine battery level and charging status. "which will not wake up the phone" -- use an alarm type that does not have `_WAKEUP` on it, and it will not wake up the phone.

Comment: @shelll: To be blunt, your chosen project is not a good "first small project" for somebody "learning programming for android". To get the best possible UI, with up-to-the-second accuracy of data, you have to do things (everlasting services) that are an anti-pattern on Android. I am steering you in a direction that may not be the best for writing a battery monitor app widget, but is a better approach for the vast majority of Android applications. IMHO, battery monitoring is a job for home screens or the OS, not app widgets.

Comment: @CommonsWare: so, for accuracy i need a service, but it will make users angry. is there another con to using a service (in my case, where the service does almost nothing) other then memory consumption? thank you for steering me in this direction, i will definitely not use a service in future applications. ...are there situations where you do recommend using a background service?

Comment: @shelll: "is there another con to using a service... other then memory consumption?" -- the issue is not a `Service`, but an everlasting `Service` (one you start and never stop). If the `Service` is mostly sitting there, the primary harm is in the RAM it ties up. "are there situations where you do recommend using a background service?" -- again, the issue is not a `Service`, but an everlasting `Service`. Use an everlasting service where it is unavoidable (e.g., VOIP client needing to maintain a persistent socket connection). Use `AlarmManager` wherever possible.